# How to Use Local font in HTML using WebView

Tags: android, html

My fonts are in assets folder. I am using WebView for displaying some HTMLs. I want to use  tag with "face" attribute in it and what i need, is to use local font.
I know this can be done with CSS styling and addressing font file like this:

```
file:///android_asset/fonts/fontname.otf
```

but with html  tag, it does not seem to work:

```
<font face="file:///android_asset/fonts/fontname.otf">A Simple Text</font>
```

Probably we just can use some pre-defined fonts! How can i do it without CSS?

Comment: Could it be that the `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML 5? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: I've already done that but i was using css, why don't you want it ?

Comment: i have no problem with css, but i want to see, is there any way without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we can't use custom fonts in html font tag!